# Netty server down (Server is running in eclipse debug mode )

Tags: java, eclipse, tcp, netty, nio

My netty server suddently stop accepting TCP connection. It works fine til last night.The server is hosted in remote, it is running in eclipse Version: "Juno Service Release 1" in debug mode.I didn't find any problem for past 7 days. What may be the issue please advice?

I have Live Boss Thread.

All the treads are running.

We are running through the eclipse is It cause any problem.

Can we run a concurrent java application in eclipse for 6 month or above?

Comment: (Sorry, cannot resist) You can run *non-concurrent* java applications in eclipse for more than six months, but concurrent ditto has an upper limit of six. Hey, come on!

Comment: @forty-two Thanks Is my server down happened because of this?